# Can we Replace MAUI Application on Existing Android Play Store Application which built on Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, google-play, maui, maui-android

I've an Application on Android Play Store which is built in Xamarin.Forms, now I've Developed a newly upgraded application on the MAUI Platform. Can I Replace the Existing Xamarin application with a new MAUI Application on Google Play Store Directly?

- Current Application is developed in Xamarin.Forms and Published on Google Play Store.
- Expecting: While Publishing an upgraded version of the same application which is developed in the MAUI Platform and Replaced with an existing Application while Publishing the MAUI Application.

Comment: Yes, as long as it uses the same ID and signing cert

Comment: Yes, this is independent of the technology you use. You could also implement a new version in Flutter or Kotlin and still replace/update the existing app with that as long as the identifier and the signing certificate are the same.

Answer (score 1):

The technology does not matter at all. As long as you use the same application identifier (the reverse domain `com.company.yourapp`) and the same keystore file that is used to sign your Xamarin.Forms app, you will be able to replace it with anything.

The Google Play Store (and this is basically true for any app store) only cares about the binary and the metadata that is associated with it, not what tech it's built with.