# Publish iOS MAUI Application on Existing Apple App Store Application built on .net Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: ios, app-store, maui, maui-ios

Is it possible to Publish iOS MAUI Application on Existing Apple App Store Application built on .net Xamarin.Forms?

- Current Application is developed in Xamarin.Forms and Published on Apple App Store.
- Expecting: While Publishing an upgraded version of the same application which is developed in the MAUI Platform and Replaced with an existing Application while Publishing the MAUI Application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we Replace MAUI Application on Existing Android Play Store Application which built on Xamarin.Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76945198/can-we-replace-maui-application-on-existing-android-play-store-application-which)

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is not a problem, as long as you use the same **Bundle Identifier**.
Convert your Xamarin to MAUI and the follow along the "[Publish a .NET MAUI app for iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/?view=net-maui-8.0)" in the MAUI docs. Same as Xamarin a .ipa-file will be created and this is what you would publish to App Store.